# Install dual boot error with grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, live-usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 11. I installed Ubuntu with Rufus on a USB flash drive. I put it in the boot sequence in the BIOS. Instead of launching the Ubuntu installation I have what you see in the screen photo. I did ls it showed me what you see in the photo.

[image]

When I boot the Ubuntu live USB only what you see in the screenshot appears. Install Ubuntu or other options don't appear when I boot the Ubuntu live USB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: @ChanganAuto sorry but this is not resolve. I have do with writing there

Comment: Understanding the process takes a lot more than 5 minutes, just reading the answers takes longer than that. For a dual-boot with Windows 11 there's only one small difference: Everything MUST be in UEFI mode beacuse, unlike 10, 11 does NOT support BIOS/Legacy mode. Understand that how yit boots is how it installs. Like always since Win8 you must disable its Fast Startup feature. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Try to disable secure boot in the bios.

Comment: You are also showing grub 2.04. Newest Ubuntu now uses grub 2.06. If Windows 11 hardware, it must be newer, so you probably need Ubuntu 22.04. Be sure to boot in UEFI mode: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: I have disable this doesn't work...

Comment: @oldfred this is not problem i have do this but when i boot usb ubuntu i have this error with grub i can't install ubuntu

Comment: Also, when i flashed linux to my usb, it created 2 partitions. You need to select the first partition. in the UEFI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

Answer (score 0):

Disable TMP as well as Secure Boot in the UEFI ( what some people still uncorrectly call BIOS ).
 Also disable fast start up in Windows. 
When you are in the Live environment click the install Ubuntu icon on the desktop. 
Make sure all your hardware works in the live environment.

Comment: i have try don't work and don't appear for install ubuntu

Comment: Did you verify the checksum of the .iso and the written usb medium? Or you can try 'Balena Etcher' or 'Ventoy' to make your medium. See if that changes anything.